# Excel: Select the newest date from a list that contains multiple rows with the same ID

Tags: date, excel-formula, distinct-values

In Excel, I have a list with multiple rows of the same ID (column A), each with various dates recorded (Column B). I need to extract one row for each ID that contains the newest date. See below for example:

|Column A   |   Column B|
|(ID)       |    (Date) |
|-----------|-----------|
|00001      | 01/01/2022|
|00001      | 02/01/2022|
|00001      | 03/01/2022| <-- I Need this one
|00002      | 01/02/2022|
|00002      | 02/02/2022|
|00002      | 03/02/2022| <-- I Need this one
|00003      | 01/03/2022|
|00003      | 02/03/2022|
|00003      | 03/03/2022| <-- I Need this one
|00004      | 01/04/2022|
|00004      | 02/04/2022|
|00004      | 03/04/2022| <-- I Need this one
|00005      | 01/05/2022|
|00005      | 02/05/2022|
|00005      | 03/05/2022| <-- I Need this one

I need to extract the above rows, where the row with the newest date is extracted for each unique ID. It needs to look like this:

|Column A      | Column B |
|(ID)           | (Date) |
|----------|--------------|
|00001       | 03/01/2022  |
|00002       | 03/02/2022  |
|00003        |03/03/2022 |
|00004       | 03/04/2022  |
|00005       | 03/05/2022  |

I'm totally stumped and I can't seem to find the right answer (probably because of how I'm wording the question!)

Thank you!

Google searches for the answer - no joy. I don't know where to start in excel with this function, I thought perhaps DISTINCT or similar...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Office 365 compatible version of Excel, you could do something like this:

(screenshot/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9g4lnZNzOO-BhqWTZfA?e=1FJIbd) refers):

```
=INDEX(SORTBY(A2:B11,B2#,-1),SEQUENCE(1,1,1,1),SEQUENCE(1,2,1,1))
```

[image: most recent to oldest date, corresponding IDs...]

This formula is superfluous albeit convenient - you don't really require the first sequence (there's only one row being returned). However, as you can see in the screenshot, using the self-same formula, this time with a leading 2 in the first argument of that sequence returns the top two (descending order) dates, and so forth.

---

FOR THOSE w/ Office 365 you could do something like this....

```
=LARGE(B2#+(ROW(B2#)-ROW(B2))/1000,1)
```

i.e. adding a "little bit" to the dates that we can subtract later and use as a unique reference (row number, original unsorted list)

[image: second method - no Office 365 ye]

As mentioned, reverse engineer, throw into an index, and voila!

```
=INDEX(A2:A11,ROUND((H2-ROUND(H2,0))*1000,6))
```

[image: reverse engineering out the lookup key]

---

caveats:

> *the round(<>,6) is purely to eliminate Excel's irritating lack of precision issue.*

> *can work if you're looking up text strings (i.e. attempting to sort alphabetically) EXCEPT large doesn't work with string (no prob, just use unicode - but good luck with expanding out the string etc.*  ☺ *with mid(<>,row(a1:offset(a1,len(<>)-1)..,1)..*

---